# javascript- localstorage-como hacer que al refrescar la página vuelva al estadio anterior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

como puedo hacer que mi página vuelva al estadio anterior cuando alguien la refresque? Cuando la página carga, debe aparecer una imagen de presentación  (con id theImage)y al clicar en los menús ésta desaparece para que veas la que has seleccionado en los menús(con id imagen1). Todo bien hasta ahí, pero cuando refrescas la página aparece de nuevo la imagen de presentación y, debajo de ésta, la imagen que has seleccionado en el menú, la cual ya debería no estar. Debería volver al estadio inicial. Como lo hago? Muchas gracias.

### JS

```
window.onload=function () {
    document.getElementById("theImage").style.display = "block";
    $(".ulmenu").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("theImage").style.display = "none";
    });
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="main">
            <div id="sidebar1">
                <nav id="nav-left" class="menu">
                    <ul class="ulmenu" id="ulleft">
                        <a href="#imagen1">
                            <p>report</p>
                        </a>  
                    </ul>
                </nav>  
            </div>

            <div id="column1">
                   <img id="theImage" src="img/panta_de_sau.jpg">
                    <div id="imagen" class="col-2">
                            <article>
                                <img class="light" id="imagen1" src="img/liceu1.jpg">
                            </article>
                    </div> 
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar el localstorage para revisar si algunas cosas de tu página ya habían sido "activadas".

Al cargar el sitio deberías comprobar que **no exista** un objeto en el localstorage. En mi ejemplo el objeto se llama `estaOculto`.

Si el objeto no existe puedes aplicar tu script original, donde tienes tu función de click en `.ulmenu`. Cuando hagas click podrías guardar en el storage el objeto.

Si cuando entras al sitio el objeto ya existe podrías aplicar una lógica que se adecue a lo que necesites.

```
window.onload=function () {
    // Checar que en el local storage no exista algo que evite que se muestre
    if ( !localstorage.getItem('estaOculto') ) {
      // Como no existe en el storage se puede aplicar tu script normal
      document.getElementById("theImage").style.display = "block";
      $(".ulmenu").click(function(){
      document.getElementById("theImage").style.display = "none";
      // Se guarda en el storage el estado.
      localstorage.setItem('estaOculto', 'SI');
      });
    }
    // Si ya existía en el storage 
    else {
      // Lo que quieras hacer
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,eres muy amable. Pero no lo entiendo. Para aplicarlo a mi ejemplo, el objeto estaOculto corresponde a mi imagen con id imagen1 ? y en el else else { // Lo que quieras hacer } no se como hacer lo que quiero hacer. Lo que desearia que pasara es que la imagen con id imagen1 desapareciera al cargar la página. O que la página volviera al estadio inicial, como si no se hubiera clicado en el menu.